# mysql - all possible combination for list of strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below kind of string attributes in mysql. 
Each attribute has comma separated values.

```
Attr1: A, B, C, D
Attr2: E, F, G, H
Attr3: I, J, K, L
```

I need each unique combination from above attributes and values.
Like:

```
AEI
AFI
BEI
```

and so on....

Right now, I am using nested while loop to achieve the same.
But as each attribute and comma separated value within it increases, performance starts getting degraded.

Can you please help me with better approach to achieve the same?

Comment: let us know what you have tried yet

Comment: @Ankit I tried normal nested while loops. First split 1st attribute, than within it another while loop which splits 2nd attribute. Then within it 3rd while loop which splits 3rd attribute and so on.

Comment: Do you have mysql queries in your loops? can you share an example of those nested while loops?

Comment: @sevle, yes after combination is determined, value needs to be fetched for the same.

Comment: It doesnt make sense to have mysql queries in your loops, since you actually need all posible combinations. Extract Attr1,Attr2,Attr3 in Arrays with 3 queries, then use a while loop to create combinations. I can't help you more if you do not include the loops and re-tag your question properly, since as @Gordon said, it is not a problem for SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please help me with better approach to achieve the same?

if you normalize the table(s) you can use cross join(s) to generate a combination list. 
It will solve your question but it wont scale very well.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(Attr1.value, Attr2.value, Attr3.value)
FROM 
 Attr1
CROSS JOIN
 Attr2
CROSS JOIN 
 Attr3
ORDER BY 
 Attr1.value ASC
```

**Result**

```
| CONCAT(Attr1.value, Attr2.value, Attr3.value) |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|                                           AEI |
|                                           AEK |
|                                           AHI |
|                                           AHK |
|                                           AGJ |
|                                           AGL |
|                                           AFI |
|                                           AFK |
|                                           AEJ |
|                                           AEL |
|                                           AHJ |
|                                           AHL |
|                                           AGI |
....
.... 
....
```

see demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/285e41/4

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. :) I will try using the same and see what different it makes in performance.

Comment: @VanitaArora . . . If you have comma-separated values, then this solution doesn't work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I will split comma separated values in temp table and then perform outer join on all tables. I am still not sure about performance but I think it will be better than basic while loop used by me. Thanks for your time :)